# Orthogonality of the sum of two subspaces

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, orthogonality

Let C and D be subspaces of vector space V. Now I understand C $\subseteq C+D$, however I don't see how come (C+D)$^\perp$ $\subseteq C$$^\perp$ and (C+D)$^\perp$ $\subseteq D$$^\perp$, where (C+D)$^\perp$ is the orthogonal complement of the set (C+D). Would anyone care to explain? Thank you.

Comment: I think what you mean to say is 
$$
(C+D)^\perp \subseteq C^\perp
$$

Comment: Yes oops thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Highlights:

$$x\in(C+D)^\perp\implies \langle x,y\rangle =0 \;\;\forall\,y\in C+D$$

And since $\;C\subset C+D\;$ , the above is true *in particular* for $\;c\in C\le C+D\;$:

$$\langle x,c\rangle=0\implies x\in C^\perp$$

Comment: Hi @DonAntonio, but how does that imply (C+D)$^\perp$ $\subseteq C$$^\perp$, how come the set of C$^\perp$ is bigger than (C+D)$^\perp$?

Comment: @DJ_ ?? Do you know how in general one proves $\;A\subset B\;$ for two sets? Well, unless I commited a miserable mistake, this is exactly what my answer shows! And in general, for *subsets* (no need to be subspaces) $\;A, B\;$ in a vectorspace with inner product, it is easy to show that $$A\subset B\implies B^\perp\subset A^\perp$$ Just think a little about it...and this general fact proves directly your question.